# HTML escape strings

Tags: java, spring, groovy

Spring has [htmlEscape](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/HtmlUtils.html#htmlEscape%28java.lang.String%29) to escape potentially unsafe HTML from user input.  I'd like to apply htmlEscape as an annotation to the backend Spring based code ([similar concept](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Text.Html.EscapeHtml/p/Java.Lang.ICharSequence/)).  This is to help prevent XSS attacks.

```
class MyCreateRequestDoc {
    @NotBlank(message = 'A name must be specified')
    @AsSafeHtml
    String name
```

I believe this calls for an AOP pattern, but I don't know how to implement such a thing in Java Spring.

I started with:

```
package com.my.company.services..security

import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import org.springframework.web.util.HtmlUtils

@Aspect
@Slf4j
@Component
class AsSafeHtmlAspect {
  @Around("@within(com.my.company.services.security.AsSafeHtml)")
  void assertProperty(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp){
      var input = 'get this from somewhere'
      return toSafeHtml(input) //return?
  }

  private String toSafeHtml(input) {
      return HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(input)
  }
}
```

And the related annotation used in `Around` above:

```
package com.my.company.services.security

import java.lang.annotation.Retention
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface AsSafeHtml {

}
```

Comment: Why not define a `SafeHtml` class, which wraps a string known to be safely escaped?

Comment: @AndyTurner - As long as the solution is DRY it should work just fine.  In other words, I don't want to litter the code with `htmlEscape`.